# Force a column to spread out to viewport with Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have a the following simple HTML structure:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <div class="card">
      <li class="cardTitle">Just a placeholder title</li>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <li class="cardTitle">Just a placeholder title</li>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <div class="card">
      <li class="cardTitle">Just a placeholder title</li>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <li class="cardTitle">Just a placeholder title</li>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <div class="card">
      <li class="cardTitle">Just a placeholder title</li>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <li class="cardTitle">Just a placeholder title</li>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

On large displays the column layout is as follows:

[image: Large Layout]

While on medium displays the column layout is:

[image: Medium Layout]

So on and so forth until on small displays it becomes a 1 stack column.

I'm trying to achieve something similar to this:

[image: Intended Layout]

How can I stretch the last column to take up all available width to spread the cards next to each other instead of under each other?

Comment: Are you trying to have 2 columns at the smallest screen widths?

Comment: I think he wants to have 1 colum in xs / 2 columns in sm / 3 columns in md / 4 columns in lg / 5 columns in xl. But since `col-`s are wrapped inside a `row` div, this gets tricky.

Comment: I think something like `display: grid` could be a better solution

Comment: @Pieterjan That's exactly what I'm trying to do. Unfortunately with Bootstrap 5 the default behaviour of the grid system results the columns to default in taking 100% of the viewport width when at <768 px. Giving the columns a set width of 50% or in this case, a class of col-md-6 allows them to split up but with an odd number of columns the last one will look deformed. [See example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozqFD.png). I've tried quite a few different remedies but none give me the desired effect. It seems I'll have to make my own grid in this case.